# Custom post type and URL

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to remove alias from custom post type? Let me tell a bit more. For instance, I've created a post type, name "Book". So URL will be `domain.com/book/post-title` or `domain.com/?post_type=book&p=528.` I want the URL as `domain.com/post-title.`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you cannot, or at least *should not*.

`www.domain.com/post-title` is interpreted as post (if your structure is `%postname%`) and/or a page - and WordPress is set to deal with them as such, including any conflicts.

You can do the following:

```
add_action('init','wpse0845_add_rule');
function wpse0845_add_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule("([^/]+)/?",'index.php?book=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

(and then flush rewrite rules, *once*).

However, you'll notice that now your pages (and depending on your structure, posts too) give a 404.

Comment: I was successful using a combination of some tricks. Rewrite rules in functions and htaccess, and some special configuration in `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => ...`
Anyway, thanks Stephen for your answer.

Comment: Tanmoy, could you perhaps supply the rest of that solution?